# Vaadin keeps giving error with @vaadin/flow-deps

Tags: node.js, npm, vaadin

Whenever I try to do anything with Vaadin, one thing that keeps giving me issues is the npm package flow-deps, or the lack thereof. Whenever I try to move my vaadin folder, it gets stuck at that directory. npm install is not working and returns this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "target\frontend" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shour\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-22T22_58_29_085Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what folder structure You have?

Comment: Seems like You've such issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/6089  have You tried to update Your Vaadin installation ?

Comment: simply find folder where package.json file exists and run `npm install` don't try to change folder structure. simply need to install it in folder where `package.json` exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, it turns out that whenever I fresh installed Vaadin and ran npm install, it installed a file shortcut @flow-deps which didn't lead anywhere. Deleting that shortcut fixed the issue.